# How to do MVC model binding with dynamically loaded form elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

Say I have a view model like this

```
class MyView
{
    DynamicViewModel MyDynamicViewModel {get; set;}
}

class DynamicViewModel 
{
    string A {get; set;};
}
```

And on the actual view markup, I load MyView.  I have an EditorTemple partial view for DynamicViewModel because I want it to be reusable and it also has some dynamic elements itself.

Also, the MyView page has it's own form elements that determine the contents of MyDynamicViewModel.  So depending on what the user types/clicks, MyDynamicViewModel will be reloaded with new info via ajax callbacks.

This works, but since DynamicViewModel is loaded dynamically, the MVC model binder has no way of knowiing that the values in the DynamicViewModel belong to the model on MyView.MyDynamicViewModel.

To illustrate, the form value for MyDynamicViewModel.A will have it's form ID equal to "A". But to model bind, I need it to be MyDynamicViewModel.A, like this:

```
<input id="MyDynamicViewModel.A" name="MyDynamicViewModel.A" type="text">
```

But this template gets loaded via ajax (the controller method returns the view as string and the javascript just updates a div with the contents), it doesn't know about the "owner" model MyView

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding your question without seeing the code in full.

From my understanding you should just be able to set the `id` and `name` attribute of the html string, after you get it back from the Ajax call.

http://jsfiddle.net/q7dLy/

If you are dealing with a more complex view model such as a form with collections you should still be able to setup the appropriate `id` and `name` attributes by following the [ASP.net Wire Format](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing `MyView` as a model to the view

You can use

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => Model.MyDynamicViewModel.A)
```

But you need to initialize this model in constructor of your `MyView` model as

```
  class MyView
    {
     public MyView()
        {
          MyDynamicViewModel =new DynamicViewModel();
        }
        DynamicViewModel MyDynamicViewModel {get; set;}
    }
```